# Adding jar to scala classpath, object is not member of package

Tags: scala, jar, import

I'm trying to use kyro serialization with scala. I've included the .jar in the classpath.

```
scalac -classpath *.jar *.scala
```

Which gave me an error about dependency libraries:

```
$ scalac -classpath "*.jar" *.scala
warning: Class org.objenesis.strategy.InstantiatorStrategy not found - continuing with a stub.
error: error while loading Kryo, class file 'kryo-2.23.1-SNAPSHOT.jar(com/esotericsoftware/kryo/Kryo.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
one warning found
one error found
```

I included those as well:

```
scalac -classpath "*.jar:lib/*.jar" *.scala
```

Now I have this error:

```
$ scalac -classpath "*.jar:lib/*.jar" *.scala
test.scala:2: error: object esotericsoftware is not a member of package com
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo
       ^
test.scala:7: error: not found: type Kryo
        val kryo = new Kryo
                       ^
two errors found
```

Attempting to compile a java file using the .jar is fine:

```
javac -classpath *.jar *.java
```

Why is scala giving me so much trouble?

Comment: Ever considered using [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/)?  I exclusively use sbt for my projects.  It saves you the hassle of managing your jars like you are attempting.

Comment: Normally I use maven for larger projects. I just wanted to write a small single file script to test something from this library. I was hoping it would be as quick and easy as doing it in java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-verbose` to see the class path seen by scalac, and where classes are loaded from.

More of a suggestion than an answer.